# How to load stock item using product_id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, stock-status

I am trying to get the `stock status (is_in_stock)` of an item. Currently, I am using the

```
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository
```

which only accepts **stock item id** to fetch the product stock item data, is there any way we can fetch the stock using the product id?
 Like:

```
$this->stockItemRepository->loadByProductId($product_id)->getIsInStock();
```

Comment: You want to check that product is_in_stock or not. Right?

Comment: that's right , I want to check the is_in_stock

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface` in your file :

```
protected $stockRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRepository
){
    $this->stockRepository = $stockRepository;
}
```

Now, Add this below code in your function :

```
$productStock = $this->stockRepository->getStockItem($productId);
echo $productStock['is_in_stock'];
```

Comment: let me check this

Comment: okay. Tell me if still it's not working for you.

Answer (score 2):

Below script helpful to get stock data using object manager

```
$productId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($productId);
print_r($productStockObj->getData());
```

OR

Use of this Block Class

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository;

class HelloWorld extends Template
{    
    protected $stockItemRepository;
        
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,        
        StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
    )
    {
        $this->stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}
```

you can call to this in phtml file :

```
$id = 1;
$productStock = $block->getStockItem($id);
```

Comment: I'm using it on a model

Comment: @pradipGarchar get() function load by stock item id not product id. Go to core file Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository.php and check get function

Answer (score 1):

The below method will work in Magento 2.3.4

```
Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository
```

But in Magento 2.3.5 it will not work. Instead, you have to use below one

```
Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product_id);
$IsInStock = $stockItem->getIsInStock();
if ($IsInStock) {
    echo "Is in stock";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$this->stockItemRepository->get($product_id)->getIsInStock();
```

Insted of this

```
$this->stockItemRepository->loadByProductId($product_id)->getIsInStock();
```

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: no, it did not work